# How to create "padding-bottom" after boxes for footer?

Tags: html, css, footer

I am trying to simply put a footer at the bottom of my html page.  I have been unable to find a decent tutorial online mainly because my content, though simple, is not standard (i suppose).

I have the following html code (just a testing page and not the real thing):

```
<html>

<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<div id = "container">


<div id = "header">
This is the header
</div>

<div id = "body">


<div class="IRL">
<div class="box"><a href= ""><img src="" width="100" height="100"></a></div>
<div class="box"><a href= ""><img src="" width="100" height="100"></a></div>
<div class="box"><a href= ""><img src="" width="100" height="100"></a></div>
<div class="box"><a href= ""><img src="" width="100" height="100"></a></div>
<div class="box"><a href= ""><img src="" width="100" height="100"></a></div>
</div>



<div id = "footer">
Testing footer
</div>

</div>
</div>
</html>
```

The relevant content of "style.css" is then:

```
html,

body    {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
}


#container  {
min-height:100%;
position:relative;
}

#container {
height:100%;
}

#body {
padding:10px;
padding-bottom:50px;   /* Height of the footer */
}

#footer {
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
height:50px;   /* Height of the footer */ //This is from a tutorial
}

.IRL {

position: absolute; top:50px; left:10px;
}


.IRL li{

margin:0px 150px 0px 0px;
list-style-type:none;

}



.box    {
margin-top: 10px;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
border: 2px solid #000000;
width:100px;
height: 100px;
color:#000000;
}
```

The problem is the footer cuts through the boxes even when i get it to be at the bottom (after a bit of tinkering).  Basically does anybody know how to create a gap after the boxes?  I had thought the padding-bottom was supposed to do that?

I hope i have been clear

Many thanks in advance. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all the absolute positioning and add:

```
.IRL {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n6tde/)

Alternatively, tweak the absolute positioning `top` and `bottom` values for the various elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link.  A handy resource.  I'll play a bit for it.  Cheers

Comment: Any idea in the case of parallel columns of boxes, where i would need to have some positioning e.g. left 100px?

Answer (score 0):

Try add a `margin-top` to `#footer`, that exceds the height of the element with `.box` items.